# Preg match is empty when regex test seems working

Tags: php

I am trying to make it with regex but obviously can't make it.

```
$matches = [];
preg_match("\[phpstart\](.*)\[phpend\]",$PiText,$matches);
```

In the `https://regex101.com/` I tried and it returns result `Group 1`. With the correct value - `echo "test"` for this string `[phpstart] echo "test" [phpend]`. But in when I use it in the script, `$matches` is an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add delimiter on your regex definition like / :

So your corrected preg_match is :

```php
preg_match("/\[phpstart\](.*)\[phpend\]/",$PiText,$matches);
```

You need to have delimiter at the start and at the end of your regex definition

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!